# Open Source Web Filters

Tags: java, spring

Can we use a filter to avoid sql injection that comes through the url? is there are open source filters for that?
Is there are such filters with Spring as well..

Please reply me

Comment: Remember `magicquotes` from PHP? They tried to do something like this, it was target of major criticism and is now deprecated ;). Request pre-processing is not a way how to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually escape the query that comes through the URL using prepareStatement() in JDBC rather than applying some sort of "filter".  If you're using an ORM implementation with setParameter() this resolves the issue that way.

Answer (score 2):

Sql injection is handled in Persistence layer (where you may use Hibernate, JPA, iBatis etc) where prepared statements are written. Make sure you use [Prepared statement.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

You really need a multi-pronged approach.  Using prepared statements or bind variables is important, but somebbody might err and let abusive queries through.  You should also configure the database so human and automated users have only the privileges they need.

Your typical user does not need `CREATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE` privileges, so don't give those to him. Lookup tables like `US_STATES` should be read-only; give no one `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` on these unless a disaster occurs. If Springfield, IL is destroyed in an earthquake and the capitol is moved, then give a dba UPDATE privileges temporarily.

Consider also writing stored procedures for the tasks users must perform. You can give the procedures their own privileges and give the user almost none other than access to them.